# mysql multiple count in single table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 query in one table t_push_member

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(`member_subscribe_at`, '%d-%m-%y') Tanggal,
  count(`member_msisdn`) 'total_reg'
FROM
  `t_push_member` 
WHERE
  `service_keycode`='nocan' 
GROUP BY
  Tanggal,
  'total_reg'
ORDER BY
  Tanggal
```

and

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(`member_unsubscribe_at`, '%d-%m-%Y') Tanggal,
  COUNT(`member_msisdn`) 'total_unreg'
FROM
  `t_push_member` 
WHERE
  `service_keycode`='nocan'
GROUP BY
  Tanggal, 'total_unreg'
ORDER BY
  Tanggal
```

how to make 2 queries into one query ?

Comment: You can use sub query to get it done in One query.

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: i want tanggal, reg, unreg in one result

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from 
( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(member_subscribe_at, '%d-%m-%y') Tanggal, count(member_msisdn),'REG' as Registered FROM t_push_member 
    where service_keycode='nocan' 
    group by Tanggal  

    UNION

    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(member_unsubscribe_at, '%d-%m-%Y') Tanggal, count(member_msisdn),'NOT_REG' as Registered FROM t_push_member 
    where service_keycode='nocan'
    group by Tanggal
)
order by  Tanggal
```

Learn more about UNION at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: @Maliq : in UNION column names also have to be the same in all the queries that return columns. See the above updated answer. It will work.

Comment: this my query 

SELECT (
SELECT count( * )
FROM t_push_member
WHERE service_keycode = 'NOCAN'
AND member_unsubscribe_at <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) AS 'Member UNREG', (

SELECT count( * )
FROM t_push_member
WHERE service_keycode = 'NOCAN'
AND member_unsubscribe_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) AS 'Member REG'
result only member reg and member unreg
and I want to add a group by date

Comment: @Maliq :Pl see the updated answer. There is already group by date in both of the queries and if you want to add any other group by then you can add it before order by. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much, its work!!.  but I had to modify again for other purposes

Comment: But it's not a very good answer ;-) ... although, to be fair, it's hard to provide a more authoritative one without seeing the actual DDLs.

Comment: @Strawberry : can you please give more details ?

Comment: @ankur.trapasiya I was thinking your solution wouldn't scale well, but I just tested it (although not on a very large dataset) and it worked just well as an alternative query I had in mind, so based on the information provided, I actually think your query's just as good as mine!

Comment: @Strawberry : it would be great if you can share your query here. And in what aspect query wouldn't scale well ?

Answer (score 0):

use "union" between the two - Instead of and